# Music and dancing in weddings?

Tags: halal-haram, music, wedding

When I go to weddings (muslim women only weddings) there is usually loud music and a dance floor. The women wear nice dresses (sometimes showing too much skin) and they dance while the loud music is playing. Is this permissible? Should I not dance? Should I not go to these weddings? (even though most or all muslim women only weddings are like this). What about the family hosting the wedding, would they be judged for paying for the singer and the dance floor?

Comment: Some forms of Music may be permissible at times of celebration, if there is nothing else haram about it. If the gathering consists of only muslim women then the dress is not of concern as the 'awrah between the same gender is relaxed.

Answer (score -1):

In Islam just duf is allowed all other music haraam. For women perda is must. Dance and loud music and pay for danceres too haraam in Islam.because it get away human from the right path.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works, and it is preferable to please cite sources and thoroughly answer the question asked.